# Why is my state not updating after useDispatch

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, state

Ive got a pretty straightforward set-up. That seems to be alright at least on my unexperienced first glance, however upon trying to dispatch an action to toggle the state, it does not seem to do anything and I can't figure out why.

this is how my store is configured:

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createReducer, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

// action
export const TOGGLE_QUIZ_MENU_CHOICE = 'TOGGLE_QUIZ_MENU_CHOICE';
export const actionToggleQuizChoices = createAction(TOGGLE_QUIZ_MENU_CHOICE);

// store and reducer
type StoreState = {
  isMultipleChoice: boolean;
}

const initalState = {
  isMultipleChoice: false,
}

const reducer = createReducer(initialState, {
   [actionToggleQuizChoices.type]: (state) => ({
      ...state, 
      isMultipleChoice: !state.isMultipleChoice 
   })
}

const store = configureStore({
   reducer
})
```

*(... then it's obviously passed via `<Provider>` )*
And later down the line in my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { actionToggleQuizChoices } from '../../../store/actions';

type Props = {
   isMultipleChoice: boolean;
}

const QuizMenu: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch()

   console.log(props);

   return (
     <button type='button' onClick={() => dispatch(props.actionToggleQuizChoices)} />
   )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState): StoreState => ({
    isMultipleChoice: state.isMultipleChoice 
})
const mapDispatchToProps = { actionToggleQuizChoices }

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(QuizMenu);
```

Now my props seems to be mapped correctly (as do seemingly my actions (though I'm new to [redux](/questions/tagged/redux)), however my actions don't seem to affect my state.

[image]

I've simplified the example for sake of quesiton, but you can see obviously I've clicked the button and the state is not affected

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem lies in what you are dispatching.

SHORT: you don't need the `useDispatch` just do `onClick={props.actionToggleQuizChoices}`

LONG: 
your

```
const mapDispatchToProps = { actionToggleQuizChoices }
```

will be translated to something like

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({ actionToggleQuizChoices: (...args) => dispatch(actionToggleQuizChoices(....args)) })
```

then inside of your component what you are actually doing is

```
dispatch(((...args) => dispatch(actionToggleQuizChoices()))(props.actionToggleQuizChoices))
```

as you can see you are dispatching a function. Functions are only interpreted either by a custom middleware or if you are using redux-thunk.

Comment: Oh, that's my bad. Was not aware of that. The name of the hook was kinda misleading to me, but I guess that's mainly my bad for not properly studying the source code. Thanks :)

Comment: glad to help. It would be nice to know why your question was downvoted though..

Comment: Was asking myself the same thing. I was actually kind of feeling down about it as well, because I did try to explain the question to best of my ability and it was mainly the fact I was confused as redux + react-redux + redux-toolkit kind of did my head in as someone who's learning it., that lead to a mistake that I believe anyone genuinely new to the technology could make and is not clearly explained in the official docs. Either way, glad to see there are still some people like you who frequent the site and are here to genuinely help! Happy holidays mate :-)

Comment: happy holidays to you too